# Сеть между двумя ubuntu 16 на VirtualBox

Tags: ubuntu, сеть, virtualbox

Пытаюсь настроить сесть между двумя виртуалками. Для этого добавил в настройках VB дополнительный адаптер с параметром "Internal Network". Далее отредактировал файл /etc/network/interfaces вот так:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
address 192.168.0.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.0.0
broadcast 192.168.0.255
```

Теперь при попытке перезагрузить сетевого демана у меня выскакивает ошибка:

```
[....] Restarting networking (via systemctl): networking.serviceJob for networking.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status networking.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Пробовал перезагрузить машину и сделать `ifconfig`, ip не поменялся на указанный. Что я делаю не так ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать просто "Сетевой мост" в настройках всех виртуалок и они с хостом будут в одной сети. DHCP тоже будет от роутера.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А что делать с файлом `/etc/network/interfaces` ? Оставить так как есть ?

Comment: Верни как было ДО настройки.

Comment: Да, виртуальную сетевуху в настройках виртуалбокса удали. Для твоих нужд она нескоро понадобится.

Comment: А разве первый адаптер не обеспечивает NAT - доступ к интернету ?

Comment: Если юзаешь NAT - нужно ещё пробрасывать порты, для других виртуалок писать маршруты и ещё куча геморняка. Тут у тебя просто в свитч воткнуто ещё 2 машины, которые доступны с любого другого компа в локальной сети и которые доступны друг для друга просто по ip или mDNS.

Comment: Но так у меня пропадает интернет соединение, ходя да, локальное остается.

Comment: Ты делаешь значит что-то неправильно. Я именно эту схему и дома и на работе использую уже лет 5 - всё нормально. Интернет пропадает где? На хосте?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42899/discussion-between-don-rumata-and-faoxis).